# Difference between MySQL 8 and MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

I have the following function and can create it inside MySQL v5.7 but I cannot create it inside MySQL 8 (8.0.13):

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsRoomAvailable(rid INT,fymd DATE,tymd DATE,bid INT)
  RETURNS BOOL
  READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE bids INT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO bids
    FROM bookings AS b
   WHERE ((b.bstart<tymd AND b.bend>=fymd) OR (b.bstart<=fymd AND b.bend>tymd))
     AND b.rid=rid
     AND b.bid!=bid;
  RETURN IF(bids>0,FALSE,TRUE);
END
```

I get the following error message: "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5"

Interesting thing is that I do not have this issue when creating a PROCEDURE, just with creating a FUNCTION.

Comment: Have you defined and redefined the Delimiter ?

Comment: How are you creating this SP? Via command line or something?

Comment: I do create this function through PHP executing SQL (JDBC Connection).

Comment: Does the posted answer work ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the Delimiter to something else other than `;` (eg: `$$`). At the end, redefine the Delimiter back to `;`:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION IsRoomAvailable(rid INT,fymd DATE,tymd DATE,bid INT)
  RETURNS BOOL
  READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE bids INT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO bids
    FROM bookings AS b
   WHERE ((b.bstart<tymd AND b.bend>=fymd) OR (b.bstart<=fymd AND b.bend>tymd))
     AND b.rid=rid
     AND b.bid!=bid;
  RETURN IF(bids>0,FALSE,TRUE);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

**P.S.** I did a comparison between the [5.7 Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) and [8.0 Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) for User-defined Functions in MySQL. Nothing seems to have changed.